# Identity Micro-services unable connect to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

A micro-services architecture based solution developed in .NET Core 3.1 / EF Core 3.1 / OpenIddict 2.1, works fine in development environment.

But in the client environment (Windows Server 2012 R2, with Server Hardening), Identity micro service couldn't able to connect to the SQL Server 2014 database server, and LINQ code which fetches data from the database does not throw any exception.

`Startup.cs`, database connection code

```
services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            options.UseOpenIddict();
        });
```

Using a sample console app (developed in .NET Core 3.1 / EF Core 3.1) able to connect to the client database, this is to verify whether server hardening causes any problem on Windows Server 2012 R2/.NET Core 3.1/EF Core 3.1.

What is causing the database connect problem in Identity micro services? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what exception do you recieve? how do you know the problem (whatever it is) is caused by the database connection?

Comment: no exception, LINQ query returns null value, so I am guessing the problem to connect to the database.

Comment: if there were an issue with the database connection, you would get an exception. Which query returns null? I am guessing the query simply has no results and hence returns null

Comment: On Client Staging environment same code works fine, but on UAT it couldn't able to execute the LINQ Query and return null, so whether it is caused by combination of Windows Server 2012 R2 Server Hardening / .NET Core 3.1 and OpenIddict 2.1?

Comment: Can't it be just that you have some data on one environment and it doesn't exist on the other? That's why I asked what which query returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, a named instance caused the problem, had to uninstall and reinstall the named instance.